# The range of the function $F$ is $S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, spheres, continuous-homomorphisms

Let $S^2:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ be the unit sphere, $\textbf{n}:=(0,0,1)$ the northpole of $S^2$ and $\textbf{s}:=(0,0,-1)$ the southpole of $S^2$.
Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^2$ ($G:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^2$ respectively) be the function that maps a point $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ to the unique intersection point between the sphere $S^2$ and the line that passes through the point $(x,y,0)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and the northpole $\textbf{n}\in S^2$ (the south pole $\textbf{s}\in S^2$ respectively).

a)  Show that $F(\mathbb{R}^2)=S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$ and $G(\mathbb{R}^2)=S^2\setminus \{\textbf{s}\}$. Give the formulas for $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$ and $G:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^2\setminus \{\textbf{s}\}$.

b)  Show  that the functions $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$ and $G:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^2\setminus \{\textbf{s}\}$ are invertible. Give the formulas for  $F^{-1}: S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $G^{-1}: S^2\setminus \{\textbf{s}\}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

c)  Show that $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$ and $G:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^2\setminus \{\textbf{s}\}$ define parametrizations of $S^2$, i.e. these functions are homomorphisms and embeedings.

$$$$

Do we get that $F(\mathbb{R}^2)=S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$ because $F$ is the intersection points between the sphere and the line through the north pole and so it cannot be mapped to the north pole? Or how do we get the range? Or do we have to find first the formula of $F$ ?

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) might be helpful.

Comment: Ah.. so is $F$ and $G$ the stereographic projection? @jasnee

Comment: Yes! The answer below explains this very well.

Answer (score 0):

The function $F$ is the inverse of the *stereographic projection* from $S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$ to $\mathbb R^2$. There are many questions concerning stereographic projection in this forum, just make a search.

The intuition is that each $\xi = (x,y,z) \in S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$ determines a unique line $L(\xi)$ containing $\mathbf n$ and $\xi$; this line is not parallel to the $x$-$y$-plane $P$ and thus intersects $P$ is a unique point $\pi(\xi)$.

$L(\xi)$ is a parameterized by $\textbf{n} + t(\xi -\textbf{n})$, $t \in \mathbb  R$. The point $\pi(\xi)$ has $z$-coordinate $0$, thus we have to solve
$$1 + t(z - 1) =  0$$
which gives $t = \frac{1}{1-z}$. Note that $z < 1$ since $\xi \ne \textbf{n}$. Thus
$$\pi(\xi) = \left(\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z},0\right) .$$
This gives the (clearly continuous) function
$$\phi : S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\} \to \mathbb R^2, \phi(x,y,z) =  \left(\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z}\right) .$$
You can do it also the other way as sketched in your question to get
$$F : \mathbb R^2 \to S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}, F(x,y) = \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1}, \frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1}, \frac{x^2+y^2-1}{x^2+y^2+1}\right) .$$

Comment: How do we get the parametrization $\textbf{n} + t(\xi -\textbf{n})$ ? Why is $z<1$ ? To get $\pi(\xi)$ we consider the parametrization of $L(\xi)$ or how do we get these coordinates? Howdid you get the $z$-coordinate of $F$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar The parameterization of the line through $a, b$ is $a + t(b-a)$. This is elementary analytic geometry, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry . The point $\xi$ lies on $S^2$, thus its third coordinate $z$ lies in $[-1,1]$. But the north pole is the only point with $z=1$. Thus $-1 \le z < 1$.  The intersection  point of $L(\xi)$ with the $x$-$y$-plane has third coordinate $0$ which gives you $1+t(z-1) = 0$. For $F$ write down the equation for the line through $(x,y,0)$ and the north pole and find $t$ such that the corresponding point on the line has Euclidean norm $1$.

Comment: Why does the corresponding point on the line need to have Euclidean norm $1$ ? Is it because it lies on the unit sphere?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, the sphere is the set of points with Euclidean norm $1$. You will find two values for $t$. One of them is $t = 1$; this is trivial because the line goes through the north pole which lies on the sphere.

Comment: And if you solve the quadratic eqaution decribing the values $t$ for which the corresponding point on the line has Euclidean norm $1$, you will see that the second solution is $t = \frac{x^2+y^2-1}{x^2+y2+1}$.

Comment: So is the line $$L(\xi)=n+t((x,y,0)-n)=(0,0,1)+t(x,y,-1)=(tx,ty,1-t)$$ and then $$\sqrt{t^2x^2+t^2y^2+(1-t)^2}=1 \Rightarrow t^2x^2+t^2y^2+(1-t)^2=1$$ ? Or have I  understood that wrongly?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that is correct. In my equation I considered the line from $(x,y,0)$ to the north pole, thus your trivial solution $t=0$ corresponds to my $t=1$.

Comment: Ah why do I get $t=0$ but you $t=0$ ? What have we done differently?

Comment: I took the same line with the "reverse" parameterization $p(t) = (x,y,0) + t(\mathbf n - (x,y,0))$. We get $p(0) = (x,y,0), p(1) = \mathbf n$. For your line we have $0 \mapsto \mathbf n$ and $1 \mapsto (x,y,0)$.

Comment: Ah ok! So at (a) we have to give the formulasfor $F$ and $G$ and to show that $F(\mathbb{R}^2)=S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$ and $G(\mathbb{R}^2)=S^2\setminus \{\textbf{s}\}$. To show the last parts do we have to show that $F$ and $G$ are bijective?

Comment: @MaryStar It is not sufficient to show that they are bijective, you have to show that they are *homeomorphisms*. To do so, simply check that $F \circ \phi = id$ and $\phi \circ F = id$.

Comment: Having checked these conditions, why does it follow then that $F(\mathbb{R}^2)=S^2\setminus \{\textbf{n}\}$ ?

Comment: Having showed this the question (b) is trivial then, right? since $\phi$ is then the inverse of $F$ so $F$ is invertible. Is that correct? Could you give me also a hint at (c) ?

Comment: Yes, correct. (a) - (c) have been proved by showing that $F$F and $\phi$ are inverse to each other.

Comment: Could you explain to me how (c) follows?

Comment: Since $F$ has a continuous inverse, it is a homeomorphism (not *homomorphism*, there is no group structure on the sphere). Regarded as a map with range $S^2$, we see that $F$ gives an embedding of $\mathbb  R^2$  into $S^2$.